"No tests" after uncommenting the webserver section
Note: So far the issue seems to be limited to Windows. Works fine on Ubuntu.
I'm trying to add Playwright tests to an Angular application. In playwright.config.ts there is a webserver section that by default is commented out. As long as I leave it commented out, playwright finds and executes my tests. However when I comment it out, it hangs for half a minute and then reports "No tests".
Repro steps:

ng new angular_e2e
npm init playwright@latest
npx playwright test --ui opens up the playwright UI and lists the sample tests
In playwright.config.ts Uncomment the webserver section, update the URL to 4200
npx playwright test --ui hangs for half a minute and displays "No tests"

For convenience, the following repo contains the code generated with the above steps:
https://github.com/techybolek/angular_e2e.git

You are correct, ideally all the information required to reproduce the problem should be encapsulated in the question. Unfortunately it should be obvious that in this case it's not possible. However the question provides all the steps required to reproduce, which is much more valuable than all the bulky generated files. Also a link is better than nothing.

The commands listed is ALL that is required to reproduce. GH does not contain any additional customizations. Are you suggesting that it might be better to remove GH from the question?

Thanks! Edited the question accordingly.

Thanks, although the packages aren't pinned, so in a year playwright@latest is going to point to something different which might make it useless to future visitors. Checking your package.json into the edit history here will make it fully reproducible for future visitors.

After cloning the git repo, on Ubuntu 22.04, "@playwright/test": "^1.44.1",, angular 18.04, karma 6.4.0, TS 5.4.2, npx playwright test --ui runs two tests regardless of webServer being commented out. npx playwright test runs 6 tests. I can't reproduce no tests being discovered or any hangs/freezes.

Thank for looking into this. Hmm.... I'm on windows, I'll try on my WSL2.

Indeed, works fine on WSL2. Another thing: page.goto('') which is supposed to go to the base URL fails for me on windows too, works fine on WSL2.
